# How to secure user passwords for a thick client that allows login when offline?

Tags: security, passwords, offline

I am working on a project that composes of C# thick client and a server where users can login to the application whether the client has internet access or not. When there is access, then we can easily make a call to the server with some salted hashed challenge response scheme to authenticate the user. But when they are offline, I can't think of any way without storing the password or its hash in some form on a local database which seems quite insecure. Anyone have any suggestions on how to best handle this scenario?

Comment: The nature of the business sector we service demands that we don't let a user even open the app to see or do anything until they are authenticated unfortunately. Otherwise the suggestions about storing the userId only and then authenticating and syncing would be ideal.

Comment: See my updated answer for one possible way to deal with this need.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should let them in to do changes and then only push those changes to the server once they authenticate?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at something like DPAPI (SecureData in .Net) to allow you to protect the password until you need it. However, I'd suggest thinking about it differently, and only architect it so you ask for the password when the user is connecting. If they start in offline mode, they operate until they go online without entering the password. Once they go online, then query the user for their password.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply store the offline work with the user information (the identity, not the password), and then deal with syncing once the network is restored. At that point, the user would need to authenticate the batch of changes.

You will likely need conflict resolution during the sync anyways, which will likely need human intervention at some point, so they would need to log in to resolve conflicts anyways. The user also would be able to verify that *they* made the changes as well.

If you need better control over letting the users use the application in offline mode, you could always store a client-side-only hash for each user that is allowed to use it offline. This way you are not storing users' actual passwords within the application but a hash of them. You would also need the same hash function built into the client, but it could be different that the one the server uses and could even use a different hash per installation if needed.

You can build in the needed sync options to update the allowed list whenever the application is connected to it's server, which would also be required to change passwords, add users, etc.

Ultimately, if you need to authenticate "for real", you need to have an accessible store of authentication pairs. In an offline scenario, the only option is to store that within the client, and at that point, the goal is to keep the important data (ie. the users' passwords) safe from prying eyes.